# flex datagrid - is it possible call a sortCompareFunction on initialize

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, sortcomparefunction

HI,

I want to call the sortCompareFunction for a particular row when the grids first loads. Is this possible? Otherwise is there a way to call a sort method on grid load after it has been asssigned the dataprovdier has been updatad

Comment: sortCompareFunction for a particular row or column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch a [headerRelease event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event:headerRelease) - I haven't tried this, but the `DataGrid` sorts upon receiving this event.

```
datagrid.dispatchEvent(new DataGridEvent(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, 
        false, false, zeroBasedIndex_of_theColumn_ToSort, 
        dataField_of_that_column));
```

If this doesn't work, grab and pass the corresponding `headerRenderer` instance as the eighth parameter to the `DataGridEvent` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Zied, in my case i need to call the sort function twice. First, when the grid first loads and second when the dataprovider is updated.

First time i call it is on a FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE. At this point i have to do some exception handling to ensure that if the dataprovider is empty that i dont try and sort it.

```
myArrayCollection.sort = new Sort();
myArrayCollection.sort.fields = [new SortField("roomName", true, false, false)];
myArrayCollection.refresh();
```

The second time i call the sort function is on a CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE event. This kicks off any time the dataprovider updates.